# Every time I do a load function on a pointcloud, my point of view changes to the middle of the pointcloud

Tags: python, pptk

I'm relatively new to pptk, and im trying to load point clouds one after another, with a fixed point of view.

the main problem is that after I set the point of view, like so:

```py
v = pptk.viewer(xyz)
xyz = pptk.rand(180000, 3)
v.set(lookat=(100, 100, 100))#---> this one is works and set the look at to x:100 y:100 z:100.
v.load(xyz)#--> changes my camera to x:0 y:0 z:0.
```

Any idea on how to set the camera setting to be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your wiev angle and position with this code below;

```
v.set(phi=0.2)
v.set(theta=0.2)
v.set(r=1)
v.set(lookat=(0, 0, 0))
```